# How to ensure user does not pass null variable to Flutter plugin?

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

Let's say, in Dart/Flutter you are designing a plugin API have a function like this:

```
static Future<void> startPlaying(Uint8List bytes) async {
    _channel.invokeMethod('playBytes', bytes);
}
```

Would it be true to say that, thanks to the null-safety feature of Dart, we are not responsible in the event that the 'bytes' parameter is passed in as null by the plugin user (and thus causing a runtime crash) because in order to do so, they would have to explicitly unwrap a nullable variable, thereby promising that it is is not null.

OR... is there some other thing we should do such as throwing an exception?

Comment: It is not possible for a plugin user to pass in `null` because `bytes` is a non-nullable `Uint8List` type. If you are calling the function like this `await startPlaying(bytes!);`, and `bytes` happens to be `null`, then an exception will be thrown before `startPlaying` is even called, and the `null` value will never be passed into the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *sound* null safety, there is no way to call that method with `null` as argument.

With *unsound* null safety, which is what you get if not every library of your program is opted into null safety, it's technically possible to pass `null` as an argument (because a non-null safe library could be doing the calling, or could be passing `null` into other null safe code, which doesn't check because it assumes null safety.)

You can choose to check the value coming in, as an extra precaution.
The language makes that hard for you, because locally the code looks null safe.
Something like

```dart
if (bytes as dynamic == null) throw ArgumentError.notNull("bytes");
```

I personally wouldn't bother with that, unless there is a real risk of something going spectacularly wrong if `null` manages to get into the code.
It's documented as not allowing a `null` value, and most well-behaved code will respect that. Eventually, when all programs are soundly null safe, that check would just be dead code.

Answer (score 0):

#### First:

if you mean the final user that use app on device, you should have a `validation` for input.

#### Second:

if you mean someone try your plugin to code the app.
you can add `required` keyword, the dart analysis give the user the error if don't pass `bytes`.

```
static Future<void> startPlaying({required Uint8List bytes}) async {
    _channel.invokeMethod('playBytes', bytes);
}
```

Comment: `required` is just useful with named parameters since they are optional by default. In the question you can see they use a non-optional positional parameter which is required by nature. The type `Uint8List` also means that `null` is not allowed to be given as this parameter.